# Is there an injector like grunt-wiredep that works for NPM dependencies?

Tags: gruntjs, npm, bower, wiredep, grunt-wiredep

Most packages nowadays are available in both NPM and Bower.  I have to have NPM around, but I'd like cut Bower out of the loop on my project.

I'm currently relying on `grunt-wiredep` to create `<script>` includes in my `index.html`.  This tool looks at all of the Bower configs to pull all the necessary js and css files into my `index.html` for me.

Is there a tool that will do the same for NPM dependencies?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would be able to do that using a module bundler like [Browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) or [Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/grunt-webpack).

For getting started with Browserify , you will need to first install it via NPM globally

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Then in your project , get the frontend library you want to include , like for example the angular library

```
npm install --save angular
```

Now you will need to use `require()` to make Browserify aware of the dependencies that it needs to fetch for the project to work (In case of Angular app, where you define the main module , add this first line)

```
var angular = require('angular');

angular
  .module('autocompleteDemo', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);
```

For setting up the grunt-browserify task , first install it in the project

```
npm install grunt-browserify --save-dev
```

and configure the task as follows

```
browserify: {
    main: {
        src: 'entry.js',
        dest: 'bundle.js'
    }
 }
```

Lastly in your index.html , you will need to add markup for the bundle.js script

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Example code can be found at https://github.com/pra85/grunt-browserify-example

Comment: And the automatic injection for CSS?

Comment: That can be done by using a broswerify plugin called [parcelify](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify/) , it works if you run it directly through the command line but with Grunt I have not been able to make it work , I have opened up an issue there ( https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify/issues/39 )  , hoping somebody would advice how to integrate it successfully

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for, and will lead many to a more complex solution than is necessarily needed.