# concat dependencies installed by npm

Tags: npm

Previously, We use `wiredep` to get all dependency lib's main file path in bower.json, and then concat all 3-rd party files as vendor.js.

```
var wiredep = require('wiredep');
// concatenate and minify vendor sources

gulp.task('vendor', function () {
  var vendorFiles = wiredep().js;

  return gulp.src(vendorFiles)
    .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetDir))

    .on('error', errorHandler);
});
```

Now, we want to use npm as package manager, is there a replacement of `wiredep`?

Answer (score -1):

As pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32572109/4446308) you can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) for that :)

Comment: Yeah，I know that，but my project architectural is ready with bower.json, i just want to move from bower to npm. If use browerify or webpack, we need do lots of works